# Работа скрипта с вновь подгружаемым контентом

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, php

Столкнулся с безвыходной, на мой взгляд, ситуацией. Делаю для сайта функцию сокращения длинного контента и отображения его на той же странице по факту нажатия на кнопку.
Установил jquery, настроил div и обрадовался, работает.
Спустя время решил ознакомиться с более ранним контентом и нажал на кнопку "Показать еще".   :)

Т.е. новости подгружаются на эту же страницу, без перезагрузки.
В общем, jquery код не обрабатывает вновь подгружаемый контент, как я только не пытался изощряться, ничего не смог сделать.

jquery поставил в самый низ страницы, так, как прочел в Интернете.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может, есть возможность заставить реагировать jquery на вновь подгруженный контент?

Мой код:

**jQuery** в футере

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(".text-wrapper").each(function(){
    var review_full = jQuery(this).html();
    var review = review_full;

    if( review.length > 300 )
    {
        review = review.substring(0, 300);
        jQuery(this).html( review + \'<div class="read_more" align="center" style="cursor:pointer">...See more...</div>\' );
    }
    jQuery(this).append(\'<div class="full_text" style="display: none;">\' + review_full + \'</div>\');
});
        jQuery(".read_more").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().html( jQuery(this).parent().find(".full_text").html() );
});
</script>
```

**div, в котором отображается контент страницы (посты):**

```
<div class="text-wrapper">куча контента</div>
```

**Код, отвечающий за подгрузку дополнительных постов:**

```
    <div class="stories-container">
сами посты (все, <div class="text-wrapper"> внутри данного кода)
        <div class="stories-wrapper">
            <?php
            $stories = SK_getStories();

            if (is_array($stories) && count($stories) > 0) {

                foreach($stories as $sk['story']) {
                    echo SK_getPage('story/content');
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
подгрузка дополнительных постов
        <div align="center">
            <div class="load-btn" onclick="SK_loadOldStories();">
                <i class="icon-reorder progress-icon hide"></i>
                <?php
                echo $lang['view_previous_posts_label'];
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, направьте в нужном направлении, желательно конкретнее и не очень далеко.   :)

Спасибо!

Comment: Решили проблему? У меня подобная проблема [https://toster.ru/q/480970](https://toster.ru/q/480970)

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно вас понял, то проблема банальна. Вам нужно навешивать события при помощи обработчика .on() http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On

Пример:

`$(body).on('click', 'someclass', function(event){...})`;

Тогда любой появившейся элемент с классом someclass внутри тэга body будет реагировать на событие click.